# Ensembling KNeighbours and Decision Tree Using Voting Classifier

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, knn, gridsearchcv, ensemble-learning

I have a classification problem for which I am trying to build an ensemble using two classifiers, say for example KNeighbours, Decision Tree.In addition to this, I want to implement it using Pipeline. Now this is my attempt to the problem:

```
steps = [('scaler', StandardScaler()),
        ('regressor', VotingClassifier(estimators=[
        ('knn', KNeighborsClassifier()), 
        ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())],voting='soft'))]
pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
parameters = [{'knn__n_neighbors': np.arange(1, 50)}, {
             'clf__n_estimators': [10, 20, 30],
             'clf__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
             'clf__max_features': [5, 10, 15],
             'clf__max_depth': ['auto', 'log2', 'sqrt', None]}]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y.values.ravel(),
test_size=0.3, random_state=65)
cv = GridSearchCV(pipeline, param_grid=parameters)
cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = cv.predict(X_test)
```

On running this following error pops up:

```
Invalid parameter knn for estimator
  Pipeline(steps=[('scaler', StandardScaler()),
                  ('regressor', VotingClassifier(
                     estimators=[('knn', KNeighborsClassifier()),
                                 ('clf', RandomForestClassifier())
                                ]
                     )
                  )
                 ]
          ).
Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```

I belive their is some error in how I have defined the parameter grid. Please help me out in this.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's nested, you'll need to specify both prefixes, like this:

```
parameters = [{'regressor__knn__n_neighbors': np.arange(1, 5), #} { And you'd probably want it to be a single grid?
             'regressor__clf__n_estimators': [10, 20, 30],
             'regressor__clf__criterion': ['gini', 'entropy'],
             'regressor__clf__max_depth': [5, 10, 15],
             'regressor__clf__max_features': ['log2', 'sqrt', None]}]
```

Also, your `max_depth` and `max_features` values switched their supposed places somehow, fixed that. (And 'auto' does the same as 'sqrt', at least for the recent versions.)